# Scrollable TabWidget or TabLayout

Tags: java, android, tabs, widget, android-tabhost

Here is a [library](https://github.com/noties/Scrollable) I got.

I had added

```
implementation 'ru.noties:scrollable:1.3.0'
```

to my `build.gradle`. But, when I implement `TabLayout` of `ru.noties:scrollable`

```
<ru.noties.scrollable.sample.TabsLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tabs_height"
    android:background="@color/md_teal_500"/>
```

[image]

[image]

I am getting the class isn't found. I am actually trying to use `TabWidget` like `PlayStore`.

I want TabWidget like that gif. How to do that? Or, is there any alternative way to do it?

I tried

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tab_host"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/rl_">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Filters"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/filters_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Adjustments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/adjustment_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#40cccccc" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

But, above source code don't gives `ScrollableWidget`.

I found an demo in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UKORtWKcl4) also. He gave source code link http://www.mediafire.com/download/7c1kd878hsvlvzr/tabscroll.rar . But, I am unable to visit that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view called NonSwipeableViewPager

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setMyScroller();
}

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setMyScroller();
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

//down one is added for smooth scrolling

private void setMyScroller() {
    try {
        Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
        Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        scroller.setAccessible(true);
        scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
    public MyScroller(Context context) {
        super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
    }
}
}
```

Here's the [git repo](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/TabActivity)