# TabContent in android

Tags: java, android

I asked some questions recently. [TabLayout for AppBarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988346/tablayout-for-appbarlayout), [Scrollable TabWidget or TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987878/scrollable-tabwidget-or-tablayout)

Nonetheless, I am using `TabLayout` for `scrollable`

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Certainly, I am creating a `Camera`. So, I want to add `TabContent`.

Like I used for `TabHost`. I want to use `TabContent` and `TabLayout` together.

```
<FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tab3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>
```

While I am using `NonSwipeableViewPager` and `TabLayout` together. I am unable to use those fragments from `Camera`. I meant I can use those `fragments` from their `fragment` class. I want to use those `fragments` from my `CameraActivity`. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the CameraActivity class to your answer? Also the Camera class is deprecated from API 21 and google recommends using CameraX https://developer.android.com/training/camerax

Comment: It is not actually `Camera`. It is completely custom camera. And, `CameraActivity` isn't needed for my answer.